# Eclipse only launches if I delete the plug ins folder in my workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

To give you guys some context, I have very basic experience with Java, and im using Eclipse on windows 7. Whenever I save a project on Eclipse and exit, the next time I try to launch it, it gives me a message telling me there's been an error and to look at the log. If I either delete my whole workspace, or delete the plug ins folder it launches perfectly, but the next time I exit it won't launch again since the plug ins folder is back.

This is a paste of the first two entries of the log, i have no idea what it means.

```
!SESSION 2016-08-30 16:20:45.457 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
java.version=1.8.0_101
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\User\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2016-08-30 16:20:53.379

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2016-08-30 16:20:53.379
!MESSAGE Widget is disposed
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getShells(Display.java:2248)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManagerUtil.getModalShellExcluding(ProgressManagerUtil.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManagerUtil.getDefaultParent(ProgressManagerUtil.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.<init>(InternalDialog.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.access$0(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler$2.run(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4203)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.msgFilterProc(Display.java:3533)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-08-30 16:20:53.381
!MESSAGE An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.partDeactivated(RetargetAction.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService$4.run(PartService.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.partDeactivated(PartService.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$18.run(WorkbenchPage.java:5030)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartDeactivated(WorkbenchPage.java:5027)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:5020)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partDeactivated(WorkbenchPage.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$4.run(PartServiceImpl.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartDeactivated(PartServiceImpl.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.setPart(PartServiceImpl.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Download a fresh version of eclipse from eclipse.org and try.

Comment: I agree with Isiva - such things are hard to debug. Don't spend much time there; it might be really better to throw away your complete eclipse and your current workspaces (maybe maybe you can import your existing projects into a new workspace; one by one later on).

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that if I run eclipse as administrator it works fine.